# Nested loops performance

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, loops, architecture

Which is better in performance, this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { }
}
```

or this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) { }
}
```

and why?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see? I've downvoted because your question should have been "*This* code is faster, can you help me understand why?"

Comment: your first code is syntactically incorrect..!

Comment: What makes you think there is a significant difference?

Comment: The difference won't be significant, but the second example will we faster.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Why do you think so?

Comment: @assylias: Because of less branch prediction failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume that the inner loop actually does something.  FredrikRedin and niculare are, of course, correct, that the number of inner loop executions will be the same.  Given that this is the case, the second example is preferred (slightly) because the second example has to set up the inner loop ten times, while the first sets up the inner loop 100 times.  Total number of loops set up:

- First example: 101
- Second example: 11

Since setting up loops takes time, the second example is to be preferred, all other things being equal (which they never are). In general, if you can divide iterations between inner and outer loops, give more iterations to the inner loop, thereby decreasing the number of iterations of the outer loop.

Comment: You mean the opposite, right? The first example has 100 iterations and set up the inner loop a 100 times.

Comment: True. Will edit, you are of course correct.

Comment: "*Since setting up loops takes time*" => why? can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, at the very least the loop control variable must be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Actually they do the same number of iterations because the '*' is commutative. In the first case the number of iterations will be `100*10` while in the second case it will be `10*100`, so both resume to 1000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same number of operations. Unless you have logic to skip iterations and/or or any of the two for loops (break/continue), why do you expect a difference in performance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they have the same performance. The reason is branch prediction.

Comment: Can you elaborate little on your thoughts. Why would branch prediction be different in the 2 loops?

Comment: This does not make sense: there is only one branch in the code.

Comment: If you look at the assembly code you will realize there are multiple branches...there is a branch each time you compare the two indexes (i and j) with 9 and 99...

Answer (score 0):

They are the same but in atomic times 10*100 is better because first iterator included 100 sub-iterator and changing of next iterator is 10 step and its better than 100 step.
For best results you can use `Atomic Integer` or `byte` to replace `int`.
`int` is 32 bit and `byte` is 8 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Empirical evidence yields they are about the same:

*(time in milliseconds with minimalist operation in loop)*

**first 1003**, second 1113
first 1012, **second 1001**
**first 1000**, second 1002
**first 1001**, second 1006
first 1013, **second 1001**
first 1001, second 1001
**first 1007**, second 1027
first 1018, **second 1001**
**first 1001**, second 1002
first 1001, second 1001
first 1001, second 1001
first 1002, **second 1000**

Theoretically, I go with *angelatlarge*'s answer. I do believe it depends on what is inside the loops: if you are constructing new objects etc. hundreds of times will be slower than tens of times.

Comment: The result depends on how many times you run them - if you include them in a method and call that method many times, it is very likely that the time will drop to 0.

Comment: @assylias It's easy to get the time to 0 when the loops are empty as the code is optimised out (happens first time). I guarantee the time will not drop to 0 if you have a Thread.sleep(1) in the loop/s!

Answer (score 0):

Both the javac compiler (that compiles java code to bytecode) and the JIT (that compiles the bytecode to assembly) are allowed to treat both loops as a no-op (which they are since there is nothing in the loops bodies).

In practice, it is unlikely that javac would do that, but very likely that the JIT would just skip that piece of code.

Bottom line: performance of java code is extremely dependent on context and for your specific question regarding loops that don't do anything, the answer is: both will most likely be skipped and run in no time.